# General clarification on viewWillAppear?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I have a general question about viewWillAppear, I pushed newly a view consider view1, now viewWillAppear is called for that method, if view1 pushed another view (view2). Now if view2 is popped view1's viewWillAppear is called again, how can I come to know in which case its called i.e (is it because of newly pushing or popping of other view).

Hope my question is understandable :)

TIA

Comment: Your question is not understandable please be more specific .....

Comment: You can add a BOOL value and check if it changes when the function is called...

Comment: How do I come to know with BOOl var?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Frankly, I do not know how to determine that condition appropriately. 
You could of course set some property of view1 in view2's viewWillDisappear method and re-set that in view1's viewWillAppear. Such like:

view1.m:

```
- (void) viewWillAppear ... {
... 

if (self.wasPopped) {...}

self.wasPopped = NO;
...
}
```

view2.m:

```
- (void) viewWillDisappear {

view1.wasPopped = YES; //you would have to have a reference to view1 or fetch it from the navigation controller stack. 

}
```

However, I strongly believe that this is not really the way you should go. Consider moving your code to the viewDidLoad method. viewDidLoad is called only once when the view(Controller) is created well before viewWillAppear is called for the first time.

Answer (score 0):

Just simply remember that whenever your view will appear on screen(it is going to be visible ) `viewWillAppear` method will be called.

In your case when view2 is popped again your view1 is going to appear on the screen that's why it's `viewWillAppear` is called again. Same way when you push new view controller, that new view controller will be displayed on the screen. Before displaying that view, that new view controller's `viewWillAppear` will be called.

I hope it makes sense.

Comment: Ya, so how can I differentiate those two cases. Is it possible?

Comment: @FerozMohideen: Hermann Klecker has provided exact code. you can use that

Answer (score 0):

You can use `BOOL` value and initialize it to `FALSE`.In `viewWillAppear` make that bool value `TRUE` and in `viewWillAppear` only check whether that bool value is `TRUE` or `FALSE` if it is true means the view is appearing for second time.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your context, you want to use...

For viewWillAppear/viewDidAppear

```
isBeingPresented
isMovingToParentViewController
```

For viewWillDisappear/viewDidDisappear

```
isBeingDismissed
isMovingFromParentViewController
```